# How do I display line numbers in Emacs (not in the mode line)?

Tags: emacs

I know how to display line numbers (and columns) in the mode-line, but I'd like emacs to display the line numbers for all the lines on the left-hand side. I've seen this done in vim and other text editors. How do I do this for emacs?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

<kbd>M-x linum-mode</kbd> (or `global-linum-mode`), and put `(global-linum-mode t)` in your `~/.emacs` (or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`) to enable it at startup.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with column numbers?

Comment: For any late readers: `M-x column-number-mode` is one way to display the current column your pointer is at.

Comment: There is neither an init.el file in my .emacs.d directory nor a .emacs file in my ~. Where can I find them?

Comment: You can create one if you don't already have a config.

Comment: This worked for me.  Heads up for Windows users - this file is located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming directory, and is called ".emacs".    Just add (global-linum-mode t) at the end of the file.

Comment: Could also be in the "C:\Users\username\" directory

Answer (score 11):

This page:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers

lists a few different options.

[monotux's answer](https://superuser.com/a/212669/48734) is currently the first option listed there. An alternative (also listed) is NLinum:

- http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html

You should be able to install from ELPA:

```
M-x package-install RET nlinum RET
```

and then use it e.g. like this:

```
(use-package nlinum
  :config
  (global-nlinum-mode))
```

Comment: Just a link is not ideal for the SX format.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Especially when the link leads to a 404 Not Found. Please fix your answer.

Comment: Thanks both - agreed, though [monotux's answer](https://superuser.com/a/212669/48734) already has all the needed information. I edited to correct the link and provide an alternative one.

Answer (score 11):

- `linum-mode` → old, hack, slow. Emacs 23 (released in 2009).
- `global-display-line-numbers-mode` → Emacs 26 (beta as of 2018-03-30)

Put this in your emacs init file:

```lisp
(when (version<= "26.0.50" emacs-version )
  (global-display-line-numbers-mode))
```

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_line_number_mode.html

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Adding `(global-display-line-numbers-mode)` to `.emacs` file works in Emacs 26!